# jQuery to JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert below jQuery code to pure JavaScript to load with JavaScript function.

**HTML**

```
<select name="select" id="select" >
    <option id="EN" value="global.html">Global</option>
    <option id="AU" value="australia.html">Australia</option>
    <option id="ID" value="Indonesia.html">Indonesia</option>
</select>
```

**JS code:**

```
function getCode () {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var uniqueNumber = now + 'a' + randomNumber;
    $.getScript("getCountryCode.js?" + uniqueNumber, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        if (country){
           var code = country;
           alert("Country code:" + code);
           document.getElementById(code).selected = 'selected';
           document.getElementById('select').onchange.apply();
         }
    });
}
```

Want to add below code in pure JavaScript format to fix the issue.

```
$('.selector #select option[id='+code+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('.selecto #select').trigger('change');
```

Comment: I'd say that there are three key things that this bit of code does. Which of them is giving you problems? You don't seem to have made any effort to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Quentin... my code works fine in jquery mode.. After built in jquery only came to know third party scripts are calling through javascript already.

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

you could try this code:

edited:

```
document.getElementById(code).selected = 'selected';
document.getElementById('select').onchange.apply();
```

Comment: Hi Sekretoz.. thanks for your comments.. I updated my question and code.. Have to my jquery code inside the javascript function. Whether your solution will work on this?

Comment: getting "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).getElementById is not a function"

Comment: Yes.. it not changing.. It shows first element on the list as default. Also trigger event not working.

Comment: options[document.getElementById(code)]. the 'code' their must be the id of your option.ahm let me find another way to trigger the event.

Comment: any solution found pls? i tried different options.. but still no clue :(

Comment: can i see the onchange function that you want to trigger?

Comment: document.getElementById('select').onchange.apply(); is the function to trigger change

Comment: yes your calling it correctly.can you please post your onchange event,because the problem might be there

Comment: is your country a boolean?then why assign it on variable code?

Comment: Its not boolean.. getting country based on IP detect using third party script and assign it as variable.

Comment: HTML code updated. On select trigger, it will load html through ajax inside the div container.

Comment: IF code is set to "AU" it will load australia.html,i think the problem is on your onchange event,

Comment: I think.. this plugin is causing the issue. http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/ ....

Comment: well i guess i cant help you with that issue